# PHP formatting in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: php, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.1

I for the life of me cannot get the namespace to format directly below the line above it sometimes this might be a doc block or more commonly a php open tag. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? If I set the 0 blank lines following a tag and preceding a namespace it gets funky.

I can either get.

```
<?php namespace foo;

// other code is here
```

Or

```
<?php

namespace foo;

// other code is here
```

I want it to be

```
<?php
namespace foo;

// other code is here
```

Am I just missing an option?

Comment: I'd look into the templates, but it's been a long time since I used Netbeans.

Comment: Only problem with templates is that it will work fine upon generating it which is great but will format it back when you use the built in code format tool.